# sending entire form in ajax and want to read entire form data in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-views

I am sending entire form in ajax and want to read entire form data in django

```js
$(document).ready(function(evt){
    var frm = $('#myform');
    $(document).on('submit','#myform',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    var thisForm=frm.serialize();
    var action=frm.attr('action');
    var method=frm.attr('method');
  //var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
 // console.log("val is"+action);
  alert("vvvv"+action);
//console.log("redmi rowef3grfwefwefjkfeo fem omfe owefm wepocm wpcm wocdm"+formData);  

   $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: {path:thisForm},
        success: function(data){
                        console.log('upload success!')
                      alert(data)
                      },
        cache: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false
    });
    });

});
```

i Am trying TO Get The data But Its Display Nothing on Page

```
 @csrf_exempt def process_file(request):
       if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.getlist('filename'):
           print (request.POST)
           cat_id = json.loads(request.body).get('path')
           print("RESULT: " + str(cat_id))
```

I want  to read data in process_file function

Comment: What do you mean by "its display nothing on page"? Are you getting the console.log and alert from your front end JS code? Are you seeing any output in the terminal from the backend (which is where those `print` statements will output to)?

Comment: Sir its display nothing on page means in views.py file process_file function i am trying to print print("RESULT: " + str(cat_id)) it print nothing. in jquery its working fine .

Comment: If nothing is being printed to console it means you're not passing the if statement (which looks wrong to me).  Try putting a print above and below it to see.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any thing to your template but using Python `print()` function. These print statements will not print data on your page but on console where your server is running from as `print()` function works for console not for webpages.

```
print (request.POST)
print("RESULT: " + str(cat_id))
```